# Laravel WhereIn with multiple options in the field itself

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.3, mutators

Normally a whereIn in Eloquent compares a value from a field to an array with options. I like to reverse that and compare a option to multiple options in the field:

field contains 'option1,option2,option3'

```
Model::whereIn('field', 'option1')->get();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You should consider changing your database design, if you need multiple values you may want a dedicated table with a relationship, not a field with multiple values.

Comment: I know, but it is a very simple way to show items based on a category. I don't want to overcomplicate my database design for this.

Comment: Well, as you can see based on your own issue, it is not a good solution.

Comment: I agree, but when I do this on, let's say, 10 models I need a lot of pivot tables for what really is a very basic filter.

Comment: If it is the creation of pivot tables that bothers you, you can check this https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended

Comment: It is not the creation but the amount of tables what bothers me, but thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your query using `LIKE`:

```
Model::where('field', 'LIKE', '%option1%')->get();
```

Documentation on the syntax is available here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

If you always add a comma `,` even after the last choice, like `option1,option2,option3,` you can use a bit of a more robust filter:

```
Model::where('field', 'LIKE', '%option1,%')->get();
```

And a comma at the start (or any other separator if that matters) would make it even better:

```
Model::where('field', 'LIKE', '%,option1,%')->get();
```

Otherwise you can have issues if one of your option is similar to another one at the end (if you have `fish` and `goldfish` as possible categories, using `LIKE ',fish,'` will guarantee that you don't match `goldfish`, while `LIKE 'fish,'` would match both `fish` and `goldfish`).

I'd recommend to store your categories like that: `/fish/goldfish/water/` and then filter using `LIKE '%/yourcategory/%'`

Comment: Not 'strict' enough when options start with the same characters,.. But thanks.

Comment: See the last part, this will make it more robust for the issue you're talking about.

Comment: Ok, I see your answer is 'growing'. I like the solution with slashes the most.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably the most reliable one.